# Find infinite collection of open sets in $\Bbb R$ whose intersection is open and nonempty

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please suggest what such a collection may be like?

Comment: There's a trivial example where the entire collection is $(0, 1)$, say, but I assume you're after a collection whose elements are pairwise distinct.

Comment: @StijnHanson Another trivial example: $(0,n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to construct such a collection:

Take any open set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, then take an infinite collection of open supersets of $S$.  Add to this collection $S$ itself.  This will ensure that the intersection is $S$, which as we know is open.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb{R}$ Fix some $\epsilon >0$. Consider $$\bigcap_{x> \epsilon}^\infty (-x,x) \cap \left(\frac{-\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$$ This will work since I have used $\epsilon$ to prevent the intervals from shrinking to zero.

$\bf{\text{EDIT FOR PROOF REQUESTED BELOW}}$: 
Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \lambda}$ be a collection of distinct open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ indexed by the infinite set $\lambda.$ Show if there exists $\beta \in \lambda$ such that $U_\beta \subseteq U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \lambda$ then $$\bigcap_{\alpha \in \lambda- \{\beta\}}U_\alpha$$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$.

Pf: By definition of intersection it is obvious that  $$\left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \lambda}U_\alpha \right)  \subseteq U_\beta$$ Further, since $U_\beta \subseteq U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ then $$U_\beta \subseteq \left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \lambda}U_\alpha \right)$$ By double containment we have $$U_\beta = \left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \lambda}U_\alpha \right)$$ so we know $\left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \lambda}U_\alpha \right)$ is an open set. $\Box$

Comment: @graydad- Can we have a more generalized collection? Your answer is correct but it is restricted for i as integers

Comment: @Bungo that should suffice as an example ;)

Comment: @graydad Isn't your infinite intersection equal to the closed set $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$? Adding an intersection with a smaller empty set is a bit cheating :-) Actually, all the answer are "cheating" in one way or another, and none addresses the real question: is it possible without cheating?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Why are these answers cheating? The only way an infinite intersection of open sets is open is if you ensure you have a smallest open interval contained in every set in the intersection.

Comment: What you state is the interesting point of the question. It does not seem obvious a priori, hence it deserves a proof. The examples given (not only yours) do not answer the question in its full generality.

Comment: @ Jean-Claude Arbaut- I concur with you. This is an example. Can we have a more formal proof?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'll attemp to write one

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work as well,

$$\bigcap_{n \geq 2} (0, 1 - 1/n)= (0,1/2).$$

Comment: Yes, and it's "trivial", in the sense that the intersection is in fact the first set in the sequence.